# Report width is larger than paper width error in VB 6 SP6 data report

Tags: vb6

I got this error even after changed my orientation to landscape.

```
Feepurpose.Orientation = rptOrientLandscape
Feepurpose.Show
```

I set property of

LeftMargin - 1440
RightMargin - 1440
ReportWidth - 8655
Paperwidth - 10800

Im using VB6 Service Pack 6

Comment: `1440 + 1440 + 8655 = 11535 > 10800`  Have you tried reducing `Margins` or `ReportWidth`?

Comment: i tried.but it comes.I dont know whether we have to change printer properties.Because in desktop PC its working.but in Laptop this error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

Set leftmargin , rightmargin, topmargin, top,Right,Left to Zero.

Answer (score 0):

When you move your mouse to the right of the "report area" you will find an icon which is a "vertical line with left and right arrow" attached to it and when you move your mouse to the bottom of the "report area" you will find an icon which is a "horizontal line with up and down arrow" attached to it. Just adjust the layout and save the report see ho it works.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved by removing the `report.refresh` function.

```
        Set report.DataSource = myRS
        report.BottomMargin = 0
        report.LeftMargin = 0
        report.RightMargin = 0
        report.TopMargin = 0
        '------ report.refresh 
        report.Show
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Set borderstyle = 4
```

4 = vbfixedToolWindow for report, and it should work